# Android disable restart after force close

Tags: android

I have a simple problem. But i cannot find any solution for this in Stackoverflow. My application restarts after i take an error with force close dialog. (I use ACRA for uncaught exceptions but either way it restarts again). How can i disable it ? What is the reason for this ?

Comment: It will restart if you don't use ACRA?

Comment: @tinysunlight Yes either way it is restart

Comment: Have you tested it on other mobile?Did you write some restart code?